# PyQGIS toggle group visibility (and recursively subsub...group visibility)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, group-layer, qt4

I would like to set visibility of a layer group and all of its children (and grand-children and so on...) using PyQGIS (QGIS 2.14.1).

Assume the groups name is g0 with subgroups g0[1...n] and subsub...groups g0[1...n][1...n][...].

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('g0').setVisible(False)
```

sets the group and ALL what comes beneath invisible, so far so good:

[image]

But vice versa

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('g0').setVisible(True)
```

sets the group visible and leaves all its children untouched, wich results in nothing visible at all:

[image]

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('g0').updateChildVisibility()
```

only touches the direct children and not recursively all the descendants:

[image]

I wonder why manually setting the root groups (g0) visibility does result in recursively setting the visibility of all beneath it at all.

Question: Do I have to implement some recursive function to set the visibility of a group and its whole big family, or is there a more convenient way to accomplish this? Or is here something buggy?

Comment: Just to mention I fixed the word visibility 7 times in your question. :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a bug. It's a feature. :D

Check boxes in the layer tree have three states (see [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#CheckState-enum)):

```
Qt::Unchecked            0  
Qt::PartiallyChecked     1 (some children are checked and some are not) 
Qt::Checked              2
```

Therefore, the `setVisible()` function expects a `Qt.checkState` value, not a boolean value. By chance, it seems that `False` is resolved to 0 and `True` to 1. The value 2 is what you're actually looking for:

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('g0').setVisible(2)
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('g0').setVisible(Qt.Checked)
```

This call will check the `g0` group and all its children (grandchildren, great grandchildren, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (QGIS 3.16):

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('g1').setItemVisibilityChecked(True)
```